# Xcode 6 Swift WKWebView keyboard settings

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a WKWebView to load a website and everything is working fine. However, I do not have access to the keyboard properties the same way I do with a textfield. Can someone point me to some resources that will help me access properties (through the gui or programmatically) of the keyboard on the web?

Comment: What type of settings are you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

The [Text Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), has a section called [Configuring the Keyboard for Web Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW12) that states the following:

> Although the UIWebView class does not support the UITextInputTraits protocol directly, you can configure some keyboard attributes for text input elements. For example, you can include `autocorrect` and `autocapitalize` attributes in the definition of an input element to specify the keyboard’s behaviors, as shown in the following example.
>
> ```
> <input type="text" size="30" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="on">
> ```
>
> You can also control which type of keyboard is displayed when a user touches a text field in a web page. To display a telephone keypad, an email keyboard, or a URL keyboard, use the `tel`, `email`, or `url` keywords for the type attribute on an input element, respectively. To display a numeric keyboard, set the value of the pattern attribute to "`[0-9]*`" or "`\d*`".
>
> These keywords and the pattern attribute are part of HTML 5 and are available in iOS. The following list shows how to display each type of keyboard, including the standard keyboard.
>
> Text: `<input type="text"></input>`
> Telephone: `<input type="tel"></input>`
> URL: `<input type="url"></input>`
> Email: `<input type="email"></input>`
> Zip code: `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"></input>`

That, of course, only solves some very specific problems in a limited number of situations, but as far as I know that's all we've got to work with, even with `WKWebView`.

I would love for someone to prove me wrong and let us know how to add a keyboard accessory view, or change the appearance of the keyboard when it's focused on a form element inside a web view in an iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

I have an HTML auth page that I display in WKWebView. The autocorrect / suggestion bar appears above the keyboard for the username field. Since I don't control the HTML, I used the following Swift 3 code and javascript to add the autocorrect attribute as mentioned above:

```
    var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {

    let autocorrectJavaScript = "var inputTextElement = document.getElementById('username');"
    + "   if (inputTextElement != null) {"
    + "     var autocorrectAttribute = document.createAttribute('autocorrect');"
    + "     autocorrectAttribute.value = 'off';"
    + "     inputTextElement.setAttributeNode(autocorrectAttribute);"
    + "   }"
    let userScript = WKUserScript(source: autocorrectJavaScript, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    view = webView
}
```

Note: The bar above the keyboard still remains, with other options, just not the suggestions.