# Custom keyboard in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, wkwebview

I want to control the keyboard displayed when using WKWebView.

I have the following swift code starting the webview:

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

It will load html that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="inputElement textFieldInput">
        <input type="text" id="textField" value="" data-clear-btn="true"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Normally the keyboard is controlled by the type option on the input field.  "num" for a numeric keyboard and "text" for a alphanumeric keyboard.  But I want to have more control.

I have done enough research to know that this can not be accomplished by using the  option on the text box.  I am fully expecting to write modify the code that opens the webview.

How can I modify the swift code to allow me to do this?

Ideally, I could define multiple keyboards and allow the html code to control them something like this: `<input type='customkb1'> and <input type='customkb2'>`

My immediate need is to disable the emojis button on the keyboard but I would like a generic solution as I will be able to really improve the usability of my application if I can define a keyboard specific to what the user is inputting.

Here is what we have found so far:
That is trick I know and use for native part of the application:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25861718/1885345

But it doesn't work for webViews
That is the way to specify keyboard from WKWebView:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28533488/1885345

But it doesn't have the option to set keyboard without emojis
That is what I use to disable third-party keyboards:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34863426/1885345

Answer (score 2):

Nice challenge! So far I have tested it on an iPad and got it half-working (with a caveat) by declaring the input field's `pattern` as such:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" value="" data-clear-btn="true"/>
```

The thing is that the keyboard actually pops up first with the numeric view but it allows to toggle the alphanumeric (without emojis) view via the lower `ABC` side-buttons.
With Javascript I copied the entered value to another field and the Regex **does not actually filter out** the entered alphanumeric characters. So far so good.

As soon as you put `A-Za-z` (as prefix or postfix) into the pattern, the emoji button comes back though.

I have tried catching the `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` but does not return the keyboard object, as I wanted to set its UIKeyboardType programmatically then, but this attribute only reflects UITextViews apparently.

Alternatively you could declare the input field of `password` type, clearing the dots with Javascript and displaying the actual value to another non-editable field...

If I find a more elegant way, I will update my answer as it is getting quite late. Cheers.

EDIT: Apparently only using a `TextInput` element with [ReactNative](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#keyboardtype) you can directly prop the `keyboardType` to the `ascii-capable` iOS keyboard which shall set us free from Emojis.

Comment: Can we see how ReactNative does that?

Comment: After thinking about it I remembered, ReactNative is not using webview so they could be doing about anything.  However, it would be interesting to know how they are doing this.

Comment: In am not that much into RN, but as far as I can see from ReactNative source code, it backs a `TextInput` HTML element (using `TextInput.js` in Libraries/Components/TextInput) with a `RCTBaseTextInputView` and a `RCTUITextField` in Libraries/Text/TextInput) with most of the job done on the Javascript side. The mapping class is `RCTConvert` in React/Base. At the end of the day I guess everything could be done and, depending on your implementation details with definitely some (long) work, it could be derived and adapted for your use case on iOS (and/or Android with extra work on pure Java).

Comment: This answer did not answer the question but he did put in good effort and provided good insight so I am awarding the bounty to @Lookaji.  There probably is no easy answer, but if someone thinks they have an answer I will create a new bounty and let them answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re looking for a way to only allow certain characters to be entered in an input field, disabling keyboard modes (the emoji keyboard, for example) isn’t the best option. There are many ways to type in unwanted characters: they can be pasted from the clipboard, or even entered in the result of text replacement (for example, you can make :) turn into ).

Input validation should be done on the webpage side, not with `WKWebView`.

Comment: Good feedback.  The problem I am solving is that it is easy for the user's finger to slip and accidentally hit the emoji button.  Then the emoji keyboard pops up.  This is annoying in a business application. If I can have fine-grained control of the keyboard then I can really improve usability, not just get rid of that annoyance.

Comment: "Input validation should be done on the webpage side, not with WKWebView.", there is a third option: do both.